# Need help converting soap post to VB.net

Tags: vb.net, post, soap

I am trying to take a soap post outline given to me by a vendor. I am not a coder, but just try to piece together what I can find online. Anything helpful would be appreciated.

Code they provided.

```
POST /ClientService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: service.velocify.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://service.leads360.com/ModifyLeadStatus"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ModifyLeadStatus xmlns="https://service.leads360.com">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <leadId>int</leadId>
      <statusId>int</statusId>
    </ModifyLeadStatus>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is what I currently have in VB.net

```
Module Velocify

    Function SOAPRequest()

        Dim Request As WebRequest
        'Dim Response As WebResponse
        Dim DataStream As Stream
        Dim Reader As StreamReader
        Dim SoapByte() As Byte
        Dim SoapStr As String
        Dim pSuccess As Boolean = True

        SoapStr = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "<soap12:Body>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "<ModifyLeadStatus xmlns=""https://service.leads360.com"">"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "<username>string</username>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "<password>string</password>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "<leadId>int</leadId>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "<statusId>string</statusId>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "</ModifyLeadStatus>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "</soap12:Body>"
        SoapStr = SoapStr & "</soap12:Envelope>"

        Try
            SoapByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SoapStr)

            Request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.service.velocify.com")
            'Request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "")

            Request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
            Request.ContentLength = SoapByte.Length
            Request.Method = "POST"

            DataStream = Request.GetRequestStream()
            DataStream.Write(SoapByte, 0, SoapByte.Length)
            DataStream.Close()

            'Response = Request.GetResponse()
            'DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream()
            Reader = New StreamReader(DataStream)
            Dim SD2Request As String = Reader.ReadToEnd()

            DataStream.Close()
            Reader.Close()
            'Response.Close()

        Catch ex As WebException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

    End Function


End Module
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. The current error is saying that I am not getting a response from the remote server.

Comment: Every instance of `soap12:` should probably just be `soap:`.

Comment: The payload is XML, so I would strongly recommend working with it as such instead of trying to do string concatenation.  You risk ill-formed XML due to missing escapes and the like.  VB's XML literals and related support for working directly with `XElement` related types may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but I've done something like that many years ago and maybe it could help you in some way. Today I only use ServiceReferences if it's available.

First thing is to put the SOAP XML in a textbox, that way you don't need to deal with all (") and slashes. Let's call it txtYourSoap. Replace the values of username, password and all you need. Then put this code inside a button:

```
    Dim xUri As New Uri("https://service.leads360.com/ModifyLeadStatus")
    Dim WebClientx As New System.Net.WebClient()
    'WebClientx.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    WebClientx.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
    Try
        MsgBox(WebClientx.UploadString(xUri, "POST", txtYourSoap.Text))
    Catch
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
```

If you get a response of 400x that will probably not work, but if it's a 500 (internal server error) it means there was communication, you'll need to adjust the Headers, Add new or reconfigure the Content-Type, the UTF-XX, etc.)